# How to add open frameworks to an existing visual studio project/solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, openframeworks

I am currently working with an existing visual studio project, and need to add open frameworks to it to continue working on another side of the project.

I am quite new to both of these tools, and have not been able to find a way to import a solution or library to an existing project.

What is the best way to accomplish this,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways

1. Add the project in the solution by right clicking on the solution and then giving reference to this solution.
2. Copying dll from the project and giving reference.
3. Install NuGet package manager and get packages from online

Here is the documentation on how to add references

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was able to add open frameworks by editing the .sln file and adding a reference to it in the same way as the sample project. Now the sample project has some external dependencies that I want to add in as well, do you know how to add an external dependency to an existing project? Thanks again!

Comment: You can install nuget package manager Web Installer. You can go online to find if this external package exists there. If yes install from there otherwise, copy the dll, paste somewhere in the solution. Right click on project, click on add references and then browse to that dll and then add it